# How can I use a function parameter to refer to a variable?

Tags: actionscript-3, function, variables, parameters, refer

Sorry if this question is a bit vague, but this has been driving me nuts recently. It's nothing too complicated, but all I want to do is have the variable '**targetVariable**' be affected by a formula. The actual problem lies in the fact that the referenced variable, being '**masterVolume**' in this case, is not getting affected by the formula, but rather '**targetVariable**' instead. I run the '**makeSlider**' function at the bottom of the script. Here's the code:

---

```
var masterVolume:Number = 0;
var panning:Number = 0;

function makeSlider(sliderType, X, Y, targetVariable) {

    var sliderHandle:MovieClip = new sliderType();

    addChild(sliderHandle);
    sliderHandle.x = X;
    sliderHandle.y = Y;

    var dragging:Boolean = false;

    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateSlider);

    function updateSlider(e:Event):void {
        panning = (mouseX/(stage.stageWidth/2))-1;

        targetVariable = ((sliderHandle.x-bar.x)/bar.width);

        output.text = masterVolume.toString();
        if (dragging == true && mouseX >= bar.x && mouseX <= (bar.x + bar.width)) {
            sliderHandle.x = mouseX;
        }
    }
    sliderHandle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, beginDrag);

    function beginDrag(e:MouseEvent):void {
        dragging = true;
    }

    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, endDrag);

    function endDrag(e:MouseEvent):void {
        dragging = false;
    }
}

function playSound(target, intensity:Number, pan:Number) {
    var sound:Sound = new target();
    var transformer:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(intensity, pan);
    var channel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();

    channel=sound.play();

    channel.soundTransform = transformer;
}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, make);

function make(e:MouseEvent):void {
    playSound(test, masterVolume, panning);
}

makeSlider(SliderHandle, bar.x, bar.y, masterVolume);
```

---

Comment: Primitives (Number, int, etc) are all passed by value.  What you are trying to obtain is passing by reference.  To get that, you need to pass an object in.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I studied the Object class and found out that I could reference the variable by making it an object in the function. Here's the updated, working script:

```
var panning:Number = 0;
var masterVolume:Number = 0;

function makeSlider(sliderType, barType, soundType, hitBoxScale:Number, X, Y, targetVariable) {

    var reference:Object = { targetVariable: 0 };

    var slider:MovieClip = new sliderType;
    var newBar:MovieClip = new barType;

    addChild(newBar);
    newBar.x = X;
    newBar.y = Y;
    addChild(slider);
    slider.x = X;
    slider.y = Y;

    var dragging:Boolean = false;

    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateSlider);

    function updateSlider(e:Event):void {
        panning = (mouseX/(stage.stageWidth/2))-1;
        reference.targetVariable = (slider.x-newBar.x)/newBar.width;
        if (dragging == true && mouseX >= newBar.x && mouseX <= (newBar.x + newBar.width)) {
            slider.x = mouseX;
        }
        if (reference.targetVariable <= 0.01) {
            output.text = ("None");
        }
        if (reference.targetVariable >= 0.99) {
            output.text = ("Max");
        }
        if (reference.targetVariable > 0.01 && reference.targetVariable < 0.99) {
            output.text = (Math.round((reference.targetVariable*100))+"%").toString();
        }
    }
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, beginDrag);

    function beginDrag(e:MouseEvent):void {
        if (mouseY >= newBar.y-hitBoxScale && mouseY <= (newBar.y + newBar.height)+hitBoxScale) {
            dragging = true;
        }
    }
    slider.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, beginDragFromSlider);

    function beginDragFromSlider(e:MouseEvent):void {
        dragging = true;
    }

    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, endDrag);

    function endDrag(e:MouseEvent):void {
        if (dragging == true) {
            playSound(soundType, reference.targetVariable, 0);
        }
        dragging = false;
    }
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, make);

    function make(e:MouseEvent):void {
        if (dragging == false) {
            playSound(test, reference.targetVariable, panning);
        }
    }
}

function playSound(target, intensity:Number, pan:Number) {
    var sound:Sound = new target();
    var transformer:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(intensity, pan);
    var channel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();

    channel=sound.play();

    channel.soundTransform = transformer;
}

makeSlider(defaultSlider, defaultBar, volumeIndicator, 10, 134, 211, masterVolume);
```